# Show that $\alpha(a)$ is also a root of $f(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $F$ be a field and $f(x) \in F[x]$ a nonconstant polynomial. If $K $ is a splitting
field of $f(x)$ over $F$ and $L$ is any extension field of $F$, suppose that $\alpha : K \rightarrow  L $ is a homomorphism satisfying $\alpha (c) = c$ for all $c \in F$. If $a \in  K$ is a root of $f(x)$, show that $\alpha(a)$ is also a root of $f(x)$.

In the case that $a\in F$, it's esay to see that the statement is true, since $\alpha(a)=a$. But what about the case where $a\in K\setminus F$?

I have been trying to understand the result by means of examples, but so far I have nothing. Could you help me with some hint, please?

Comment: Hint: apply $\alpha$ to the equation $f(a) = 0$

Comment: @DavidLui The idea would be to use the fact that $\alpha$ is a homomorphism, yes?

Comment: Yes, $\alpha(\sum c_i a^i) = ...$